# ListboxItem design for Multiresolution App windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, listbox, windows-phone-8.1

I want to develop app which is targeting to Multi resolution Device i Windows Phone(i.e. : 480*800  to 1080*1920)
this is my code for list box

```
<ListBox x:Name="LstContact">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border BorderBrush="#cbc6c0"
                                    BorderThickness="0,0,0,2"
                                    Margin="10">
                                <Grid >
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"
                                               Foreground="Black"
                                               FontSize="22"
                                               Margin="10" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

And output should be like this

[image]

please help to that

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: border line is not coming in proper way. Width of boder is depending on text lenght of text

Comment: please check this link I have pasted same question here and what problem I am getting I have written. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/1a8a32ee-6f06-416e-bb28-3cd51712c1ba/wpsl-listboxitem-design-for-multiresolution-app?forum=wpdevelop

Answer (score 1):

It is Silverlight, so just put something like Width="480" to your Border and you are done.